# Get next class name in same element

Tags: jquery

I try to get next class in same elemet.

Example:

```
class="ct-series ct-series-a"
```

I want any class next to ct-series

Below is my code example.

```
var series =$(this).closest('.ct-chart-bar').find('.ct-series').next().find('.class');
```

But it shows undefined.

I use ChartJS and I can get the label name but cant get the series name. The other way solution I think get the series classname.

Here my bar chart.
[image]

[image]
Please help me.

Comment: For what reason do you need this? Relying on the class attributes to be in order is a code smell of a larger problem. Given the context of the classes I'd suggest using something like `class="ct-series" data-series="a"`, then you can select by class and find the specific value from the `data` attribute.

Comment: Can you provide some html examples?  Your *title* implies you want to find the text "ct-series-a" (next class in same element) but your *attempt* shows navigating and using `.next()` (which finds the next element).  So a little unclear exactly what you want out.

Comment: i use ChartJS Barchart. And it differentiate the bar by ct-series-x. For example, 1st bar starts with 'a' and so on..

Comment: Ok, so why do you need to get the next class from the same element?

Comment: I can get the label name but cant get the series name. And this the only way if I can get the class name, it might solve my problem.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - why are you reading the HTML to get your chart data?  Surely you provide the chart with the data, so you already have that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery, but here's one way to do it.
I added a `if statement` to return the first one if you try to get the next class of the last on the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function findNextClass(targetClass) {
    var allClasses = $(`.${targetClass}`).attr('class').split(/\s+/)
    var targetClassPosition = allClasses.indexOf(targetClass)
    
    // If it's last return the first one
    if(targetClassPosition + 1 === allClasses.length) {
      return allClasses[0]
    } else {
      return allClasses[targetClassPosition + 1]
    }
  }

  console.log(`Next of .ct-series: ${findNextClass('ct-series')}`)
  console.log(`Next of .ct-series-a: ${findNextClass('ct-series-a')}`)
  console.log(`Next of .test: ${findNextClass('test2')}`)
  console.log(`Next of .another-test: ${findNextClass('another-test')}`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ct-series ct-series-a test2 another-test"></div>
```

Comment: @Nurul Glad I could help. Make sure to accept this answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).attr('class')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot change the HTML then you could potentially use the `classList` collection to retrieve the next class on the element. You can retrieve the position of the known class in the array and get the following one based on the indexes.

You should note that this is an extremely brittle approach though, as the order of `classList` may not be guaranteed to be the same as in the DOM, and you will need additional checks to ensure that there are following classes behind the one searched for.

I do not recommend this approach at all, I am simply adding the below example for the sake of completeness.

```js
let classes = document.querySelector('#foo').classList;
let nextClass = classes[[...classes].indexOf('ct-series') + 1]

console.log(nextClass);
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="ct-series ct-series-a">Foo</div>
```

A far better approach would be to amend the HTML so that the common class is retained on all elements, but the identifying metadata is put in to a `data` attribute. This way you can select the element directly and read a known static attribute:

```js
let series = document.querySelector('#foo').dataset.series;
// let series = $('#foo').data('series'); // jQuery alternative

console.log(series);
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="ct-series" data-series="ct-series-a">Foo</div>
```